# Creating empty geodatabase with all feature datasets according to another geodatabase structure using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, clip, file-geodatabase, feature-dataset

I have a file geodatabase which includes a lot of feature datasets and each feature dataset has lots of Features. I am going to do clipping through all the Features using ArcPy Code. However, the clipped Features are created in the same feature datsets. I would like to know how I can chnage this script to have a new FGDB with the same feature datasets but just include the clipped Features.

```
import arcpy, os
database = r'C:\Users\...\WEB_clip_4half.gdb' 
clip_feature = r'C:\...\Kapsel_.shp

try:

    arcpy.env.workspace = database
    datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='Feature')


    for dataset in datasets:
        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(database,dataset)
        features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for feature in features:
            if '_clipped' in feature:
                arcpy.Delete_management(in_data=feature)
        else:    
             arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features=feature,clip_features=clip_feature, out_feature_class=feature+'_clipped')
except Exception as e:
  print("Found an error - {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Do you have got new data sets or need to create them?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some indentation issues in your code-snippet, else statement should be aligned with the if statement.  As far as creating the geodatabase and feature datasets you may use these arcpy methods:

[Create File GDB](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-file-gdb.htm)

[Create Feature Dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-feature-dataset.htm)

Within your logic before you create the geodatabase and feature dataset in your destination geodatabase you will want to include the [Exists](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/exists.htm) method to evaluate if these files exist already or not.  You may also want to consider using [Walk](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) to better traverse through the source geodatabase to pull out feature dataset names to hold as a variable for creation of new feature datasets in destination geodatabase.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have empty GDB and your final dataset wil have same spatial reference as a clip shp.

Script creates new dataset and then does clip.

Change new_database (and sr (**spatial reference**) if necessary):

**More info about sr in dataset you can find below:**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-dataset.htm

Your code little fixed:

```
import arcpy, os
database = r'C:\Users\...\WEB_clip_4half.gdb' 
new_database = r'NEW'
clip_feature = r'C:\...\Kapsel_.shp'
sr = r'C:\...\Kapsel_.shp'
try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = database
    datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets('Feature')
    for dataset in datasets:
        features = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for feature in features:
            if '_clipped' in feature:
                arcpy.Delete_management(feature)
            else:
                CreateFeatureDataset_management(new_database, dataset, sr)
                arcpy.Clip_analysis(feature, clip_feature, os.path.join(new_database, dataset, feature))
except Exception as e:
    print("Found an error - {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. May I ask what is the "NEW" for GDB? is that the Name of that or how it is going to be created?

Comment: I run this Code but I do not get any Feedback. where could be the Problem?

Comment: Just add path to the new GDB.

Comment: I actually did it but still I donot get any new GDB

Comment: I assumed you have empty GDB -- please read what I wrote. Just make new gdb, fill path and should it work.